# SharePoint Designer Form - Field Label to Remove Hyperlink

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I am using a label for a field in a SharePoint Designer Editform to simply show existing data in that field and make it uneditable. How to modify the tag to remove the hyperlink behaviour but keep the text?

Current Tag is:

```
<asp:label runat="server" id="ff20{$Pos}" text="{@AssessmentEmployeeName}" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff20',$Pos),'Text','','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@AssessmentEmployeeName')}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In design view, there should be an arrow to the top right of the field you want to modify. Click it and there's an option to change the format of the field. I can't remember the exact wording, but plain text or something similar should be one of the options.

Comment: Hey again Erin, I can send you a screenshot perhaps. That is the first thing I tried but the weird thing is that when you switch it to text, it turns my  nice label into a long garble of code which doesn't render into anything even in the browser. It's very strange. What do you think? Want a screenshot?

Comment: I'll try it myself and let you know. Just to make sure, it's a hyperlink field?

Comment: And do you want to display the link (e.g. http://www.google.com) or the description (e.g. Google)?

Comment: Basically I have a Lookup field which looks up an Employee name from another list. When I display this field in the form, I want it to not be editable, so tried inputting it as a label, but SharePoint provides a link to this individual's HR data in the other list which is a big nono. If i try entering as text, it puts the employee name in <a> tags which don't render in the browser. what the heck?

Comment: In code view, go into the table cell (<td> tag) that contains your data, then delete the opening and closing <a> tag lines.